# "Who will I talk to on Saturday?" or ""Who will I talk on Saturday to?"

Tags: word-order

Which word order is most correct for the following question?

1. Who will I talk **to** *on Saturday*?
2. Who will I talk *on Saturday* **to**?

Also what is the grammatical/semantic reason why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. Who will I talk to on Saturday?
> 2. Who will I talk on Saturday to? (awkward if not ungrammatical)

The short and boring answer to this question in that sentence (1) is much better than sentence (2), which some speakers may actually find ungrammatical.

The more interesting and helpful question is *Why?*.

To understand the answer to this question, we need to understand the difference between a Complement an an Adjunct.

**Complements**

Different verbs set up different types of slots for other phrases in the sentence. So for example, the verb *PUT* sets up a slot for a person doing the moving, a second for the thing that is being moved and a third for the destination of that thing, usually realised by a preposition phrase. All English verbs set up a slot for a Subject. Here we are interested in the slots that follow the verb. The phrases that fill these slots are called Cᴏᴍᴘʟᴇᴍᴇɴᴛs. Using the verb *PUT*, we can see that if one of these slots isn't filled, the sentence will often be ungrammatical:

- *We put the elephant. (no thing being moved - ungrammatical)
- *We put in the zoo. (no destination - ungrammatical)
- We put the elephant in the zoo.

**Adjuncts**

Aᴅᴊᴜɴᴄᴛs are extra bits of information that we tag on to a sentence. You can think of them as embellishments. They are completely optional and don't fill any special slot set up by the verb. In the following sentence, the preposition phrase *with my friends* is an Adjunct—because it doesn't fill any special slot set up by the verb *VISIT*:

- I visited Bertha with my friends.
- I visited Bertha.

We can see from the sentence above that the phrase *with my friends* is an extra, grammatically optional phrase. The sentence *I visited Bertha* is a well-formed and fully complete sentence without it.

---

**The Original Poster's example**

Consider the following two sentences:

- *I visited with my friends Mary. (ungrammatical/awkward)
- I visited Mary with my friends.

We can see from the example above that, in general (and if not set off by special intonation), the Complements of the verb need to come before any Adjuncts. If we put the Adjunct, *with my friends*,  before the Complement, *Mary*, the sentence will be very clunky and may even be considered ungrammatical. The longer the Complement is, the more acceptable it is to have it after the Adjunct:

- I visited with my friends all the different people who had contacted us over the last few weeks.

The Original Poster's example uses the verb *TALK*. The verb *TALK* sets up a space for a Subject - usually a noun phrase - and, optionally, also a space for a person being talked with, usually described in a preposition phrase.

4. I will talk to Bob on Saturday.
5. I will talk on Saturday to Bob. (awkward)

In the examples above we can see that when the Complement *to Bob* occurs before the Adjunct *on Saturday*, the sentence sounds very natural. When this order is reversed the sentence is very awkward.

The Original Poster's example has a gap after the preposition *to* which we understand represent *who*:

- Who will I talk to [<s>him</s>] on Saturday.

This preposition phrase *to ___* needs to come before the Adjunct *on Saturday* or the sentence will sound a bit awkward. This is especially the case because the audible part of the preposition phrase, *to*, is very short:

- Who will I talk on Saturday to? (awkward)

Comment: Remember that the *on* is optional: I’ll see you next week, next year, next Saturday, Saturday.

Comment: @tchrist Quite right. I should make that clearer. Can't do right now. Will endeavour to tomorrow. If I forget, and you notice (or anyone else does), please kick my arse!

Comment: I think you overstate the case by suggesting *Who will I talk on Saturday to?* might be considered "ungrammatical", given the basic construction is no different to, say, [*(subject) speak **now** to (audience)*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I+speak+now+to+the%22). Granted, ***on** Saturday* includes a preposition, whereas ***now*** doesn't, but native speakers don't usually mind piling up prepositions (that's something ***nns*** worry about more, probably because English uses more prepositions than most other languages).

Comment: ...re your comment on the original ELU version of this question, one context where a *careful* speaker might prefer to put a time-based adverbial element including a preposition *before* the preposition identifying the "object" is if that object happens to be a very long compound element. So someone might reasonably prefer *I'll speak **on Friday** to the butcher, the baker, and the candlestick-maker*. In which context I think it wouldn't be ridiculous for someone else to reflect that sequence with *That's all very well, but who will you speak on Saturday to?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hmmm. "I'm going to speak now to Bob" sounds very awkward to me. I'm not sure what's going on with the grammar there, but *now* works in a different way from *on Saturday*. Consider *I'm going to now speak to Bob* and *I'm going to on Saturday speak to Bob*, where the latter is definitely wonky but the former is fine. Re your other examples in your second comment, the first works because the object is very long (as described above), the response works because it is echoing the original. And that kind of possibility is why there's a *may* in there! However, I'm surprised ...

Comment: @FumbleFingers .. you feel that that response would be more careful than *who are to going to speak to on Saturday* - which would be equally viable, if not more elegant.

Comment: I'm not necessarily trying to establish that there are *any* contexts where you personally would find it more "elegant" to put a preposition-based adverbial element before a preposition-based object. My original comment simply said there *might* be contexts where someone "we" might accept as a careful speaker would do so. You and I are obviously capable of presenting ourselves as careful speakers, but that needn't imply we must always agree on the most elegant sequence in any given case. There's always room for personal style, and I think "grammar" isn't really the issue on this one.

Comment: *I visited with my friends Mary* is certainly ***very*** "awkward", but imho it's not "ungrammatical". *I saw with my own eyes what he did* is essentially the same construction, but I've no special reason to prefer that over *I saw what he did with my own eyes.*

Answer (score 1):

The first has a much less clunky construction, go with that one.

Comment: That is not necessarily the case; context is important. For example, if you want to emphasize *to* then the end of the sentence would be the strongest placement: *Yes, I understand we will talk on Saturday— but who will I talk on Saturday to?*

Comment: @choster Exactly so. The end of the sentence is where we place the most important/focussed information, when we can.

Comment: @Araucaria . . . and for this reason it is a shame that in English we cannot (usually) place the focus of the sentence - the verb - at the end, where some other languages do (usually).

Comment: @NigelJ I agree! But there, is one construction we can use to do that. That's when we have an intransitive verb with a preposition phrase complement and we then prepose the PP. So for example instead of "And she strode onto the stage" we can have "And onto the stage she strode." :)

Comment: @Araucaria It's difficult for us in English. In other languages they can bundle up so much meaning (genitive, dative and ablative meanings plus gender pronouns) and just push the lot at the end of the sentence into one inflected verbal form.

Comment: It's still not a construction that sits comfortably with me, because splitting the verb sounds so clunky. Perhaps that's a personal thing. If I wanted to emphasise the 'to', I would reorder the sentence to avoid splitting out the verb: 'On Saturday, who will I talk to?'